# How can I make my decrypt method more efficient?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am making a simple transposition cipher.  I am testing the program with the word "computer" with the secret key "5,2,8,3,7,1,4,6", where the encrypt method will put the 5th letter 'u' in the first position, 2nd letter 'o' in 2nd position, 8th letter 'r' in 3rd position...

So the output would be:
original: computer
encrypted:uormecpt
decrypted:computer

Right now my decrypt method is of O(n^2). How can I make this faster?

Where char[] y would be uormecpt.  The z[j] - 1 is the offset as my iterator starts from 0, but my key starts at 1.

```
public static char[] decrypt(char[] y, int[] z)
{
    char[] decrypted = new char[y.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++)
        {
            if (i == z[j]-1)
                decrypted[i] = y[j];
        }
    }

    return decrypted;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can assume that every index in the encrypted message is included in the key, You can loop over the key and encrypted message together, placing each letter into the correct decrypted message slot directly:

```
public static char[] decrypt(char[] encrypted, int[] key)
{
    char[] decrypted = new char[encrypted.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++)
    {
        decrypted[key[i]] = encrypted[i];
    }

    return decrypted;
}
```